# "Ты можешь думать(,) что хочешь". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?
**Ты можешь думать(,) что хочешь.**

Answer (score 3):

> Ты можешь думать, что хочешь. (А подсознательно ты этого не хочешь -
>   мысли порой обманчивы.)
>
> Ты можешь думать что хочешь. (Мне всё равно, что ты думаешь об этом; я сделаю по-своему.)

На мой взгляд, второй вариант несущественно модифицирует неразложимое сочетание "думай/делай что хочешь/угодно" (таковые не трактуются как СПП).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, это неполное придаточное предложение.

Правило:

Запятой отделяются также неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные предложения, например: **Он не понял, в чем дело; Рад помочь, чем смогу; Запомнил, чему учили; Люди знают, что делают; Сделайте, что нужно; Могу предоставить все, что угодно; Он понимает, что к чему; Садитесь, где свободно; Ругали все, кому не лень; Болтал, не знаю что.**

Но:

§114. Цельные по смыслу выражения

Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе НЕРАЗЛОЖИМЫХ сочетаний, например:

**Ты что хочешь думай (Л. Толстой)**

Розенталь, Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография и пунктуация.