# Я сделал все(,) что мог

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, будет ли в данном случае запятая: я сделал все(,) что мог. Или здесь цельное выражение без запятой?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443632/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%88%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%88%d1%8c-%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f/443635#443635

Answer (score 2):

*Я сделал **всё, что мог**.*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с **неполным** местоименно-определительным придаточным, поэтому запятая ставится.

Цельные по смыслу обороты имеют **значение одного слова,** например:

*Жители остались без работы, и народ разбрелся промышлять **кто чем может**: рыбной ловлей и охотой (= разными делами)*.

*Прежде, бывало, на именины или к празднику поклонишься учителю головою сахару и фунтиком чаю, или **кто чем может**  (= другими подарками) по состоянию, ― и дело в шляпе.*

Но: *Целый день сидим в деревянной избе и занимаемся, **кто чем может** (заняться)*. Это сложное предложение с неполным придаточным, которое не имеет значения одного слова.

[**Цельные по смыслу выражения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146) (Розенталь)

Comment: Какая же вы умница, с каким удовольствием я читаю ваши объяснения!

Comment: @ИванРоманов Вы скрыли свой ответ, а я его всë равно вижу, на красном фоне. Это как?

Comment: @Максим У вас уже достаточно баллов, чтобы видеть все удалённые ответы.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец А-а-а, спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: Я случайно написал комментарий не в тот раздел.)

Comment: @Иван Романов Спасибо, Иван. А мне очень хочется увидеть ваши ответы или комментарии)